# Image dimensions and file size limits for PNG files in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, exception, default.png

I'm working with Flash 4.5, and reading a lot about image manipulation. I understand the limits Flash has with JPG images - one can process images up to 30000 x 30000 pixels without  problems. However, with PNG files if the image is larger than 8191px either in width or height or it's file size is bigger than 16Mpix, the image won't get processed.

When I load an image with `FileReference` the system freezes and it never triggers the  COMPLETE event which is why the image doesn't get processed. I also can't access file data such as width or height, perhaps due to missing exceptions.

How can I access image dimensions and size without the need to use PHP for that?

Comment: I don't see a way to get information about the file without actually loading it.

Comment: FileReference is used to get a reference to the file on the local system with user input, right? I thought, once you had that reference you could get access to the file as a ByteArray and perform 'processing' on it that way before sending it to the server.  I'm unclear which aspect of FileReference is freezing the system.  Perhaps if you share some code, that may help.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. Can you please explain it in more detail?